# Es posible hacer un delay en python sin que se pare el programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hola hoy me he preguntado si sería posible hacer un delay en segundo plano o algo para que no se detenga el programa. es posible?

me gustaría hacer que cada 2 segundos se trasladara un rectángulo a una posición x
y después de otros 2 segundos que desaparezca. Todo esto sin detener los demás procesos.

Edición:

Después de hacer el código tengo un problema. Al poner que desaparezca exactamente en el doble de tiempo en el que aparece hay un problema y es que no desaparece porque la aparición y desaparición se contradicen.

Código para explicar mejor:

aquí está la clase:

```
class Laser1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/laserH.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 176
        self.rect.top = 400

    def update(self, dt):
        pass    

    def move_1(self, dt):
        self.rect.left = 176
        self.rect.top = 400

    def move_2(self, dt):
        self.rect.left = 1000
        self.rect.top = 700
```

aquí están los temporizadores:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT + 1, 700)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT + 2, 1400)
```

aquí está la detección de evento:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1:
        laser1.move_1(dt)        

    elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 2:
        laser1.move_2(dt)
```

es como si USEREVENT + 2 nunca sucediera. Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Comment: Si, el enfoque normalmente va a ser crear otro hilo que se encargue de la tarea bloqueante (u otra forma de concurrencia). ¿Podrías agregar algo de contexto de lo que quieres hacer para poder ser más específicos?

Comment: editado con lo que quiero hacer

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando de PyGame?

Comment: sí la idea es hacerlo con pygame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PyGame hay dos métodos que pueden y suelen ser usados para este tipo de tareas:

- **`pygame.time.get_ticks`**: Este método nos da los milisegundos pasados desde que `pygame.init()` fue llamado.
- **`pygame.time.set_timer`**: Permite lanzar un evento de forma repetitiva cada x milisegundos y que podemos capturar en la cola de eventos y lanzar una respuesta cuando esté presente dicho evento.

En principio con ambos métodos podemos jugar lo suficiente para adaptarlos a multitud de situaciones que requieran temporizar o programar ciertas tareas sin bloquear por supuesto el mainloop.

Para ilustrar un poco su uso vamos a ver dos ejemplos:

---

### Sprite cambia de posición cada x tiempo de forma repetitiva.

Un ejemplo son las piezas del tetrix. Para esto podemos usar `pygame.time.set_timer`. Por supuesto que las posibilidades no se limitan a mover el objeto, podemos realizar cualquier tarea de forma repetitiva cada x milisegundos.

Podemos realizar múltiples llamadas a `pygame.time.set_timer`, cada una tendrá su propio temporizador e irá colocando el evento asignado cuando toque en la cola de eventos.

Para detener un temporizador para un evento dado basta con volver a llamar al método pasándole 0 en al segundo argumento (milliseconds).

```
import sys
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *



ANCHO = 400
ALTO = 200
NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60


class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("square.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centery = ALTO / 2


    def move(self):
        new_x = self.rect.left + ((ANCHO-self.rect.width)/4)
        if new_x > ANCHO:
            new_x = 0
        self.rect.left = new_x



def game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 25)

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    square = Square()
    all_sprites.add(square)

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
    fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Creamos nuestro timer, que lanzará el evento cada segundo (1000 ms)
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT + 1, 1000)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # comprobamos si el timer ha lanzado el evento
            ## En caso afirmativo llamamos al método move del sprite.
            elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1:
                square.move()

        dt = fps_clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0
        all_sprites.update(dt)
        ventana.fill(NEGRO)
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Hacer que un sprite se mueva a una determinada posición pasados dos segundos desde que se creó y pasados otros dos segundos se destruya.

Esto es algo similar en principio a lo que quieres, en este caso vamos a usar `pygame.time.get_ticks`. Al pulsar el espacio se crea un nuevo sprite (se limita a 5 sprites simultáneos) , cuando pasan 2 segundos desde que es creado se mueve al centro de la pantalla, pasados otros dos segundos desaparece:

```
import sys
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *



ANCHO = 700
ALTO = 695
NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60


class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Square, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("square.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(random.randrange(self.rect.width//2, ANCHO-self.rect.width//2),
                          random.randrange(self.rect.height//2, ALTO-self.rect.height//2))
        self.init_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    def update(self, dt):
        # Comprobamos los milisegundos que tiene el sprite de existencia
        ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.init_ticks

        # Si han pasado mas de 4 segundos desde que se creo lo destruimos
        if ticks >= 4000:
            self.kill()

        # Si han pasado  2 segundos desde que se creo lo movemos
        elif ticks >= 2000:
            self.rect.centerx = ANCHO/2



def game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 25)

    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    squares = pygame.sprite.Group()

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO, ALTO))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
    fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE and len(squares) < 5:
                    square = Square()
                    squares.add(square)
                    all_sprites.add(square)

        dt = fps_clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0
        all_sprites.update(dt)
        ventana.fill(NEGRO)
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son solo dos ejemplos simples para intentar ilustrar una idea general, dependiendo de la situación particular podemos adaptar el código para cubrir las necesidades específicas.

Si alguien quiere reproducir los ejemplos, este es el sprite usado (*`square.png`*):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola se que hace unos días no se comenta pero tengo que preguntarte algo. Voy a editar el texto

Comment: Hola @ElAlien123 ,  el problema es que  ambos temporizadores lanzan el evento a la vez a los 1400 ms, esto causa que solo el primer `elif` se ejecute ya que en un bloque `if-elif-else` el momento en el que el `if` o un `elif` se evalúa como `True` y se ejecuta el resto **ni siquiera se evalúan**, aunque la condición se cumpla. Si cambias el orden de los `elif` o haces que ambos sean `if` esto no ocurre. ¿Existe alguna razón para tener dos timers en vez de uno solo dado que el delay del segundo es múltiplo del primero?

Comment: si uno hace aparecer el rectángulo y el otro lo hace desaparecer

Comment: cada uno cumple una de las 2 funciones

Comment: podrias ayudarme?

Comment: Hola @ElAlien123 La causa de tu problema es lo que comento arriba sobre como funciona el elif ¿Has probado a cambiar el orden de los elif como comenté arriba? De todas formas sigo pensando que es mejor usar un solo timer, al menos con lo que muestras no se justifica usar dos, lo complica todo además de ser menos eficiente. ¿Lo que quieres es que cada 700 ms cambie de una posición a la otra reiteradamente? Si es así bastaría con un condicional en el método que compruebe la posición actual y un solo timer con un delay de 700 ms.

Comment: a la perfección gracias